# python read parquet empty strings as missing values

Tags: python, pandas, string, null, parquet

I have data that looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'b', ''], })   
df.to_parquet('df.parquet')
```

When reading the file, I want to read the empty string ('') as a missing value (pd.NA or similar).
Reason is that this is the deafult behaviour when reading it as a .csv, and I'd like to preserve the same without introducing additional processing steps (i.e. doing a replace() after reading the file)

Answer (score 0):

This way, when reading the Parquet file, any empty strings in the specified column will be converted to pd.NA.

import pandas as pd

```
# Define a function to convert empty strings to pd.NA
 def empty_string_to_na(value):
    return pd.NA if value == '' else value

# Read the Parquet file with the specified converter
df = pd.read_parquet('df.parquet', converters={'col': empty_string_to_na})

# Now, empty strings in the 'col' column will be read as pd.NA
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
What version of pandas or other dependencies are you using?
It doesn't recognise that argument to me with pandas 2.2.0